# Greyish spots behind a peach's stone, what could they be?

Tags: botany

I'm sorry if it's a silly question, but what are those greyish spots behind the stone of this peach (or whatever this is)? What are they for? Are they safe to eat? The fruit is ok from the outside

[image]

Comment: it is some type of mold,you should probably not eat that one.

Comment: I concur, looks like it has a yeast or bacterial-infection - a very common thing in fruit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Callus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callus_%28cell_biology%29) can develop inside peaches (https://www.tasteofhome.com/article/peach-callus-tissue/), between the mesocarp and the endocarp. [Callus is edible and harmless](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36931/is-it-safe-to-eat-the-white-dots-in-peaches). It's a tissue composed of unorganised [parenchyma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_tissue#Parenchyma) cells, which in turn are multi-purpose cells that can be found in a number of "soft" tissues with metabolic purposes including, but not limited to, the mesocarp and the endosperm. Callus' main purpose is to seal damaged tissues, see for instance:

- [this blogpost](https://www.eatortoss.com/moldy-peach-pit/) that explains the difference between mold and callus *in a peach where there actually is a mold infection* (which you should not eat)
- [its counterpart](https://www.eatortoss.com/is-that-mold-in-this-split-pit-peach/) where there is no mold, but a considerable amount of callus (way more than you have there) was produced because the stone had split open; this one would be safe to eat, once you've ascertained that there is no mold, although callus may contain pieces of hard tissue from the stone.

Small quantities of callus can appear as leftovers form older and smaller lesions.

Comment: Which begs the question, how could that peach get "wounds" from inside? 

Comment: A peach is not waterproof you know ;)